# Only one result appearing in JavaScript when converted from php/json

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a php query and have set to result to json using json_encode. I have printed the result using echo, when doing this each result from the query appears in json format.

I then want to convert the information so that I can use it with in JavaScript. I simply echo the result but only one result from the query seems to get pass over.

Here is my php code

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT appointment_time, appointment_date FROM Appointments");

if (!$sql) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
}

$appointments = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $appointment[] = $appointments;

    foreach ($appointment as $appointments) {

        $appointments = array('title' => 'Unavailable', 'start' => $row['appointment_date']. 'T' .$row['appointment_time'].'+08:00');

    }

    $json = json_encode($appointments);

    echo $json;

}
```

Here is my JavaScript

```
events:[
             <?php echo $json;?> //'2018-12-12T15:00+08:00'
        //}, 
        //{
            //title: '',
            //start: '' //'2018-12-12T12:00+08.00'
        ]
```

Comment: I would recheck your variable names. There seems to be some conflicts. e.g. $row = array('title'...... Why are you assigning something to $row?

Comment: I have changed my code a little, see my question

Comment: I have posted an answer please check and mark as correct, if helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I'd recommend not using mysqli, but I'll stick with it here. A higher-level abstraction layer like PDO is much easier to work with. At the very least you should modernize your code to use mysqli's object interface.

So you only need a single loop, to go over the database results. Your other loop was going over nothing, so would never have been executed. You certainly don't want to be echoing anything within a loop, this would result in output that is not JSON. Finally, you should set a header so that your JavaScript knows you're sending JSON.

```
<?php
$sql = $con->query($con,"SELECT appointment_time, appointment_date FROM Appointments");

if (!$sql) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . $con->error());
}

$appointments = array();

while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    $appointments[] = array(
        'title' => 'Unavailable',
        'start' => $row['appointment_date']. 'T' .$row['appointment_time'].'+08:00'
    );
}

header("Content-Type: application/json");
$json = json_encode($appointments);
echo $json;
```

Comment: thank you, this worked perfectly, I made a few changes to work with my program.

Answer (score 0):

You have two loops. The while loop: which has access to each row of the results and is looping through them with the variable $row each time. You are adding this $row into your appointments array.

Then you have the foreach loop over your $appointments (which is incrementing because of the $row being added each time through the earlier while loop). In this foreach loop, you are assigning each appointment into the same variable $row (which is being used by your outer while loop).

So there is a conflict of variable naming. If you intend to print the results of the query, you can do the following.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

    echo json_encode(array(
        'title' => 'Unavailable', 
        'start' => $row['appointment_date']. 'T' .$row['appointment_time'].'+08:00'
    ));

}
```

If you intend to have a json result.

```
$json = json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

Comment: You dont echo json_encode in a loop you will end up with invalid json, eg `{}{}{}`. You add the data to an array in the loop and after it then echo the json_encode of that array

Comment: Which is why it was noted "If you intend to print". Have updated :P

Comment: this still doesn't fix the problem